# what's the best way to implement logging during transactions in T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql, logging, sybase, transactions

I want to implement a simple debug log, which consists of a table into which I insert insightful messages about the current state of a transaction. How do I stop inserts to this table being affected by rollbacks on the transaction that I'm trying to debug? In Oracle I can use `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` to ensure that the inserts are done outside of the transaction, but what are my options in T-SQL? How do you implement logging in your shop?

*NB: I'm not using SQL Server, I'm using Sybase 12.5.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally tracked down the Sybase manuals on line.  According to the [documents](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp), it looks like your only way out is to log via [RPC](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1029418) to an external log server.

Comment: I'm not sure that your links work there, the URLs are both the same and it resolves to a description of global variables (at least for me). The advice on the other hand is spot on, sadly.

Comment: Stupid frame-based web sites and their broken navigation.  I fixed it by changing to a single link to the root of the document tree.